# how to call stored procedure with optional arguments

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

my Store procedure having 4 In type parameters.i want to use only 3 parameters when i call stored procedure in php mysql .

My stored Procedure is

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `usptregister`
(
 IN ID bigint, 
 IN name varchar(100), 
 IN email varchar(100),
 IN phoneno varchar(15)
)

BEGIN

Insert INTO register
(id,fname, emailid, phone) values 
(id,name , email ,phone)  ;
END
```

and my php code where i am calling stored procedure passing  only 3 parameters.

```
$call = mysql_query("CALL usptregister('0','".$_POST[name ]."','".$_POST[email ]."') ");
```

This code is working when i am passing same no of arguments when i am calling stored procedure.
I am new in stored procedure .so please help me.

Comment: Couldn't you pass the fourth argument as null?

Answer (score 0):

Optional parameters are not supported by MySQL

I suggest you to pass the fourth parameter as `null`. Then in the procedure you can check if is `null` or not.

```
BEGIN
   IF param IS NULL THEN 
      -- statements ;
   ELSE 
      -- statements ;
   END IF;
END$$
```

EDIT:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15975

Although the request is 9 years old it's still not done.

Comment: it will work but if u have so many no of arguments then this trick will not work . i dnt have to pass  null value or string .

Comment: and by using your trick for every parameter i have to use if and else condition .if u have more then 30 parameters then u have to write it again and again.i have made it for large batabase.

Comment: There's no other option you can do this or you will have to write a procedure for each case.